# Python - determining if parameter is an Integer

Tags: python, parameters, integer

I'm relatively new to Python. I'm suppose to come up with a basic Program that can figure out if the parameter has an integer in the function or not. I'm not sure what to put into the blanks. I don't typically use if/in type pairings. The base of the function is this:

```
def is_number(char):
            if  (somethinghere)  in  (somethinghere):
                    return True
            else:
                    return False
```

results should be:

```
is_number('4')
   True
is_number('nothing')
   False
```

Comment: Normally, you would also just write `return (somethinghere) in (somethinghere)` rather than use the `if` statment with Boolean literals.

Answer (score 5):

The usual way in python would not be with if/else but rather with try/except:

```
def is_number(char):
    try:
        int(char)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of ways to do this, but I think the exercise is suggesting that you use this method:

```
'a' in 'abcde'
Out[1]: True

'f' in 'abcde'
Out[2]: False
```

You should think about how to apply this to your specific example.

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_number(char):
   return char.isdigit()
```

You can use  [str.isdigit](https://www.google.ie/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tutorialspoint.com%2Fpython%2Fstring_isdigit.htm&ei=wQUiVPOZN4HhywORzwE&usg=AFQjCNGHHuQJZjeuPdAXUz0La9rSn5hbMw&sig2=Qt9jnb8IU2uDE4dxBZD-LA&bvm=bv.75775273,d.bGQ) if you are dealing with positive numbers

You would probably want to use a `try/except` for a more general use but using a `float` not an `int` or decimal numbers will not be considered numbers:

```
def is_number(char):
    try:
        float(char)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True
```

You also don't need an else in the code if `False` is  returned your code  will not go any further.

It is the same using `return char.isdigit()` the outcome will be either `True` or `False` so no need for `if/else`.

```
In [4]: is_number('4.3')
Out[4]: True

In [5]: is_number('0.3')
Out[5]: True

In [6]: is_number('03')
Out[6]: True

In [7]: is_number('foo')
Out[7]: False
```